# Adding charts to existing SmatGWT project

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

I'm currently using SmartGWT LGPL edition. Now I'd like to add HTML5 charts to the project so I'm willing to buy few SmartGWT Pro licenses. I tried the 60 days trial version to build a proof of concept and I failed. I couldn't make even simplicity theme to work with the Pro version.

My question is what are the steps of adding Pro components at the minimum to make charts working? I mean precisely the changes to proj_name.gwt.xml, index.html and the server jars needed (if any).

BTW, I don't need all Pro server components, I'll continue using the GWT Rpc based legacy services we built over the time. Eventually I may need the Pro components responsible for pdf/excel export.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE TO FIRST MAKE CLEAR THAT IT IS NOT LEGAL TO USE YOUR LGPL LICENSE AS YOU ARE ABOUT TO READ AND I RECOMMEND YOU GO AHEAD TO BUY THE PRO LICENSE TO ACCESS THESE FUNCTIONALITIES IF YOU HAVEN'T DONE SO BUT SINCE

> My question is what are the steps of adding Pro components at the minimum to >make charts working?

I have a working solution as below:

1. unjar both jars for LGPL and PRO, to access;
   all module descriptors such as 
   **com\smartgwt\SmartGwt.gwt.xml**, 
   smartclient javascript files such as 
   **ISC_Core.js**
   in 
   **com\smartclient\public\sc\modules** 
   and smartgwt java source files in
   **com\smartgwt\client\widgets\**
2. copy 
   **Charts.gwt.xml,ChartsNoScript.gwt.xml,Drawing.gwt.xml and       DrawingNoScript.gwt.xml**
   from PRO and paste them in the equivalent path in LGPL, overwrite incase asked.
3. copy 
   **ISC_Charts.js and ISC_ISC_Drawing.js**
   from PRO to LGPL and jar back your LGPL distro
4. Add 
   **ISC_Charts.js and ISC_ISC_Drawing.js** scripts
   to your host html file as you do for **ISC_Core.js**;
5. Ensure you inherit **SmartGwtNoScript.gwt.xml** in your module descriptor instead of **SmartGwt.gwt.xml** and you are ready to go
6. Incase on running you encounter an exception like **FacetChart is a part the Charts Module which comes with Pro Edition or better. Please see smartclient.com/product for details on licensing.**
   go to that source file such as
   **com\smartgwt\client\widgets\chart\FaceChart.java**

```js
 if ("LGPL".equals(SC.getLicenseType())) {
   throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("FacetChart is a part the Charts Module which comes with Pro Edition or better. Please see smartclient.com/product for details on licensing.");
 } else if (SC.hasCharts() == false) {
   throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("The Charts module must be loaded to use FacetChart.  See the LoadingOptionalModules overview in the \"docs\" package of JavaDoc for instructions.");
 }
```

remove those checks from the default constructor, jar back your distro and re-run.

**I hope this solves the problem**